# XSL: Issue with tokenizing in the for loop

Tags: xslt, tokenize

I am using the following stylesheet for displaying a table in the excel workbook with the data. I am not able to get the desired result instead it is displaying as differently as given below.

Suggestions Pls?

The stylesheet used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="test1" select="str:tokenize('1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5','$,$')" />
    <xsl:variable name="test2" select="str:tokenize('a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e','$,$')" />
    <xsl:for-each select="str:split('1a$,$2b$,$3c$,$4d$,$5e','$,$')>
        <row>
            <cell Index="1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$test1[position()]" />
            </cell>
            <cell Index="2">
                <xsl:value-of select="$test2[position()]" />
            </cell>
        </row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Result:

1 a

2 b

3 c

4 d

5 e

Where as the result displayed as

a b

c d

e

It seems like the it is displaying the latest tokenize values.
How to get respected values.

Comment: Could you please provide us with a more complete stylesheet? You are using functions in a namespace bound to `str`, but we do not know where these come from. Are you using extension functions with Java? Some custom functions from an online resource?

Comment: The str is a namespace which refers to "http://exslt.org/strings"

Answer (score 2):

Good question, +1.

**It seems to me that instead of**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$test1[position()]" />
```

**this must be**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$test1[position() = current()]" />
```

**Exactly the same observation holds for the second** `<xsl:value-of>`

**Explanation**:

Any expression

```
 $var[position()]
```

is equivalent to:

```
$var
```

because `position()` can only have values >= 1 and `[position()]` means *the boolean value of*  `position()` , and the boolean value of any non-negative number by definition is `true()`.

If we want to select the $k-th node in the node-set $var, in XPath 1.0, which is weakly-typed and it isn't known that `$k` holds an integer, we have to write:

```
$var[position() = $k]
```

**Here is a complete, corresponding XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="test1" select=
        "tokenize('1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5','\$,\$')" />

        <xsl:variable name="test2" select=
        "tokenize('a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e','\$,\$')" />

        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize('1a$,$2b$,$3c$,$4d$,$5e','\$,\$')">
            <row>
                <cell Index="1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$test1[position()]" />
                </cell>
                <cell Index="2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$test2[position()]" />
                </cell>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (ignored), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<row xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <cell Index="1">1 2 3 4 5</cell>
   <cell Index="2">a b c d e</cell>
</row>
<row xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <cell Index="1">1 2 3 4 5</cell>
   <cell Index="2">a b c d e</cell>
</row>
<row xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <cell Index="1">1 2 3 4 5</cell>
   <cell Index="2">a b c d e</cell>
</row>
<row xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <cell Index="1">1 2 3 4 5</cell>
   <cell Index="2">a b c d e</cell>
</row>
<row xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <cell Index="1">1 2 3 4 5</cell>
   <cell Index="2">a b c d e</cell>
</row>
```

Comment: In the loop, Position() acts as counter, as tokenize splits the string based on the delimiter and results into node-set, we can use position() as index to get the specified value from the node-set

Comment: this did not work for me. When ever I try to print the values of the tokens I always get the test2 values instead of test1 and test2 respective values.

Comment: @Bugude: See the update to my question. I don't know well the spec of the EXSLT functions, but in standard XPath 2.0 the `$` character must be escaped as `\$`.

Comment: Yes, in the standard XSLT 2.0 some of the special characters should be escaped using '\'. Is there any way we can achieve this using XSLT 1.0 as the application that I am working on is using the version 1.0 of XSLT.

Comment: I could get the result using XSLT 2.0 using different approach also but could not get the same using XSLT 1.0

Comment: @Bugude: You'd be successful if you use: `str:split('1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5','$,$')[normalize-space()]`  instead of using `str:tokenize()`. The EXSLT `str:tokenize()` function uses ever *character* in the second argument as a delimiter, however you want the complete string contained in the 2nd argument to be used as the delimiter -- this is exactly what `str:split()` does.